# Save Json list of Strings in Spring/H2

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, request

I would like to post a simple list of strings to my Spring application:

```
[
    "aaaa",
    "bbbb",
    "ccc",
    "ddd"
]
```

Do I really need an entity class which matches my @RequestBody or can I do it in an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can send them would be as request parameters or as request headers or as path variables.
using request parameters -

```
http://localhost:8080/abc?strings=aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddd
```

In the controller, you can get the list of strings using the @RequestParam annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc")
public void method(@RequestParam List<String> listOfStrings){
//some logic
}
```

Using path variables -

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddd
```

In the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc/{listOfStrings}")
public void method(@PathVariable List<String> listOfStrings){
//some logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better usind POST instead of GET.